# HTML Email not centering in outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

So I coded an HTML email using tables however, the email is refusing to center in outlook, I think this has something to do with the fact that the software i am using is stripping out the header information. how would i center the following with a background colour?

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; background-color: #f8f8f8; vertical-align: center; "
<table class="fullSize" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f8f8f8;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f8f8f8">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" valign="top">
<table class="outSide" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;" align="center">
<table class="titleTable" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#8AE872">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#b8d9ec">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px; border-collapse: collapse;" align="center">
<div><img class="fullImage" style="text-decoration: none; width: 600px; height: 193px;" src="xxx" alt="" width="600" height="193" /></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="introBlock" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; background-color: #ffffff;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="introText" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border-collapse: collapse; color: #313131; border-top: white solid 15px;" align="left" valign="top">
<table class="leftInnerContent" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; width: 570px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="leftInnerBody" style="color: #080935; padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px; margin: 0px; border-bottom: 10px solid white; background: #ffffff;" align="left" valign="top">
<table class="leftInnerStack" style="margin: 5px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; color: #080935;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="leftInnerStackText" style="width: 520px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;">
<p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em;">Dear Jane Doe,</p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus magna turpis, tristique ac ligula id, dignissim venenatis nulla. Suspendisse tincidunt orci eget diam dignissim, a varius nulla aliquam. Vestibulum sed sagittis mi.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 7px; background-color: #8b69d3; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none; color: white;"><a style="padding: 5px 15px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff!important;" href="@@SURVEY_URL_PLACEHOLDER__DO_NOT_ERASE" target="_blank"><span style="color: #fff!important; font-weight: lighter; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px;">ANSWER SURVEY &nbsp; ⟩ ⟩ ⟩</span> </a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="leftInnerBody3" style="color: #080935; padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px; border-bottom: 10px solid white; background: #f8f8f8;" align="left" valign="top"><img style="max-width: 530px; height: auto;" src="xxx" alt="" width="530" height="247" />
<!-- <table>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td pardot-region="" style="padding: 7px; background-color: #080935; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff!important; "><a href="#" style="padding: 5px 15px; text-decoration:none;color: #ffffff!important;" target="_blank"><font color="#ffffff" style="color: #ffffff!important; font-weight: bold;">Get stared &nbsp;</font> </a></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table> --></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<table class="outSide" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="12" align="center" bgcolor="#f8f8f8">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f8f8f8;" align="center" valign="top" width="600px">
</td>
</tr>
<!-- <tr>

            <td align="center" width="600px" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f8f8f8;" valign="top">
               <p><a style="font-size: 16px; color:#484D51; text-decoration: underline;" href="www.interoute.com">www.interoute.com</a></p>
            </td>

          </tr> -->
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f8f8f8;" align="center" valign="top" width="600px">
<p style="font-size: 12px; color: #81888d; text-align: center; line-height: 1.5em;">&copy;  <a href="@@OPT_OUT_PLACEHOLDER__DO_NOT_ERASE">Unsubscribe</a> @@FooterCompany @@FooterCountry @@FooterCity @@FooterPostCode @@FooterAddress1</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to start over and focus on the formatting of your code. It's broken and will never read correctly in many email clients.

As an example, you have a div that is not closed:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; background-color: #f8f8f8; vertical-align: center; "
```

You're missing the `</div>`

The opening table closes, but there's a `</td></tr>` directly after the closing table that has no opening table header or table row or cell.

In addition, you did not include your style sheet in your sample, but you have references to classes in your table structure. So we have no idea if there are additional problems with your styles.

As an aside, your email does center in Outlook. At least without the style sheet. It doesn't center in Gmail. The state of your current code is sloppy and could lead to needless poor results, which is why I encourage you to reformat it before you continue.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the email `body` with two important steps.

- Add a wrapper `<center>` element
- Have a wrapper `table` with fixed pixel size (percent size can expand to full-width).

This is the [specific part](http://blog.edmdesigner.com/the-basics-of-modern-html-emails/#usetablestosupportwordbasedoutlooks) for a basic centered email HTML template in Outlooks from our blog series that may be helpful. There are also posts on background image and layout method topics in the series, if you need deeper foundation.